# Django Channels 2: two authentication methods

Tags: django, django-channels

how i can implement multiple authentication methods for my django channels app?
I mean, i have a Token based auth and a AuthMiddlewareStack.

How i can mantain these two authentication in order to manage the in session django auth for my internal application websocket data consumer/notify/etc... and adopt the websocket token authentication for the third-party apps?

Here is my routing.py:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            app.routing.websocket_test
        )
    ),
    "websocket": TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            app.routing.websocket_test
        ]),
    )
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can stack them together, i.e wrap one of the auth stack in the other. Like `FInakMiddleqareStack = TokenMiddlewareStack(AuthMiddlewareStack)`. Then use the `FInalMiddlewareStack` in your router

Comment: Thanks @Ken4scholars, i've solved yesterday with the implementation that i've posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem implementing an Universal Authentication Middleware stack, the docs of Django Channels, lacks about these examples.

In any case, i've implemented a hybrid authentication stack that supports: Session, Token header and Token urlpath Authentication methods, works flawlessly:

**WSTokenAuthMiddleware.py:**

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from django.utils import timezone

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.db import close_old_connections


class WSTokenAuthMiddleware:
    """
    Token [Querystring/Header] authorization middleware for Django Channels 2
    """

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
        query_string = parse_qs(scope['query_string']) #Used for querystring token url auth
        headers = dict(scope['headers']) #Used for headers token url auth
        if b'token' in query_string:
            try:
                token_key = query_string[b'token'][0].decode()
                token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)
                scope['user'] = token.user
                close_old_connections()
            except ApiToken.DoesNotExist:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
        elif b'authorization' in headers:
            try:
                token_name, token_key = headers[b'authorization'].decode().split()
                if token_name == 'Token':
                    token = Token.objects.get(key=token_key)
                    scope['user'] = token.user
                    close_old_connections()
            except ApiToken.DoesNotExist:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
        else:
            pass #Session auth or anonymus

        return self.inner(scope)

UniversalAuthMiddlewareStack = lambda inner: WSTokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

**Routing.py:**

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": UniversalAuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            ...
        ),
    ),
})
```